# 30 sec timeout Angular RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Best way to implement timeout with modal:

petitions/petition_info if connection was not successful - returned "state": "rejected there is a red screen bar at the bottom of the screen "Error of connection to the "Prompt Payment System" the screen state is the same as at the initial transition

if connection was successful - "state": "processed" there is a green "System of fast payments is connected to the account" snackbar at the bottom of the screen the message "In order to make a transfer you should connect the system to your account" disappears the checkbox becomes unavailable for editing, and the fields for entering details are available.

in case of the accepted status preloader appears on the screen, petition_info is looped until the final status processed or rejected, timeout 30 sec

if timeout is over 30 sec: a modal window appears with the OK button "Application for registration in the Fast Payments System successfully accepted". If you press OK - the transfer screen closes, the user goes to the Home screen

My implementation now:

```
interval(1000)
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() => this.crossBorderService.getPetitionInfos()
                    .pipe(last())
                ),
                takeUntil(interval(30 * 1000 + 1000)),
                takeUntil(this.acceptedTimer$),
                takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            )
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    if (res.state !== 'PROCESSED') {
                        this.onSuccessConfirmSbpSms(res.state);
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.handleErrors(error);
                },
                () => {
                   // Show modal window
                },
            );
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is?  What behavior do you see with your current implementation.  What behavior do you wish to see?

Comment: I wanna show modal when interval ended and res.state === 'PROCESSED', is there a way to do it by pipe or I can use response in complete?

Comment: you don't have access to the response in the `complete` callback.  You could do it in the next callback by adding `else { this.showModal() }` or you could also do in the pipe inside of a `tap` operator: `tap(res => { if(res.state === 'PROCESSED} this.showModal() })`.  I'd prefer to keep the response handling logic together, so I'd put them both in `tap` or put them both in the `next` call back of your subscribe.

Comment: @BizzyBob If I do this, this.showModal() will execute even if the interval is still running

Comment: I need to show it when ```takeUntil(interval(30 * 1000 + 1000))``` or ```takeUntil(this.acceptedTimer$)``` and ```res.state === 'PROCESSED'```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd timeout [using the `timeout` operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timeout). A timeout situation is a exceptional / error case, so you'd handle it in the error path (or in a `catchError` somewhere)

The basic method would be like so:

```js
import { timeout, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';

// Method 1, basic
someSource$.pipe(
  timeout(30_000)
)
.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: err => {
    if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
       console.error('there was a timeout!');
       return;
    }
    console.error('some other error happened');
  }
})
```

There are a lot of different settings on the RxJS `timeout` operator, you can have it timeout waiting for the `first` value, you can have it timeout `with` some other observable (or even a custom error if you use `with: () => { throw new MyCustomError() }`)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: 
Using timer to stop interval after 30 second. For show modal on res.state === accepted just created boolean.

```
interval(1000)
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() => this.someService.Request())
                    .pipe(last()),
                ),
                takeUntil(this.acceptedTimer$),
            )
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    const state = res.state?.toUpperCase() as State;
                    if (state !== 'ACCEPTED') {
                        return this.onResponse(state);
                    }
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.isAccepted = false;
                    this.handleErrors(error);
                },
                () => {
                    if (this.isAccepted) {
                        this.openModal();
                    }
                },
            );

        timer(30 * 1000)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.acceptedTimer$.next();
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).